# Different Jquery Behavior in Chrome and Safari .on/.change select boxes

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, callback

I have several html select boxes on a page.  I need to get the value of these checkboxes.  The following code behaves just fine in Chrome, but I have debugged it in Safari and seem to be getting back a null for country_id.

Tested:
Chrome 38.0.2125.104
Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25)
JQuery 1.11.0

HTML (i removed most of the options from the select to make it more terse)

```
<select class="form-control pad-input col-md-6 country" data-state-field="#birth_state_id">
<optgroup label="North America">
<option selected="selected" value="228">United States</option>
<option value="244">Zimbabwe</option></optgroup></select>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.country').change (function () {
    var state_class = $(this).data('state-field');
    var country_id = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Please post the related HTML code as well.

Comment: By the way, `.change` is just shortcut for `.on('change'` in this case.

Comment: Thank You.  I have removed the duplicate/alternate code to reflect the feedback that you gave me.  I will post the HTML as well.